# Passing a Safearray of custom types from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, com, serialization, safearray

how can one use a `Safearray` to pass an array of custom types (a class containing only properties) from C++ to C#? Is using the `VT_RECORD` type the right way to do it?

I am trying in the following way, but <strike>`SafeArrayPutElement` returns an error when trying to fill the safearray</strike> the reference to the array of classes gets to the managed code as a NULL.

I have something like the following in the managed world:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IStatistics
{
    double Mean { get; set; } 
    double StdDev { get; set; } 
}

[Serializable]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Statistics : IStatistics
{
    public Mean { get; set; }
    public double StdDev { get; set; } 
}
```

Unmanaged world:

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
...
SAFEARRAY *pEquationsStatistics;

// common dimensions for all arrays
SAFEARRAYBOUND dimensions[1];  
dimensions[0].cElements = 2;   
dimensions[0].lLbound = 0;    

pEquationsStatistics = SafeArrayCreate(VT_RECORD, 1, dimensions);
...

for (long i = 0; i < dimensions[0].cElements; i++)
{
    long indices[1];
    indices[0] = 0;

    ... 

    // Equation statistics
    IStatisticsPtr pIStatistics(__uuidof(Statistics)); 
    pIStatistics->PutMean(1.0); // so far so good

    result = SafeArrayPutElement(pEquationsStatistics, indices, pIStatistics);

    ...
    indices[0]++;
}
```

Please note that the I am able use the `SafeArray` to pass other arrays of `BSTR` with no problems between the two applications. So this is something peculiar to passing a structure.

Stefano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure if I understand your question right, but maybe you need `VT_DISPATCH`?
I think if you want it to work with `VT_RECORD`, then your struct should actually be a struct (not a class) and also needs the `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]` attribute.

**Edit**: Can it be that the error you first got was `DISP_E_BADINDEX`? What exactly is `indices` in your code? What does it contain? (You know that the signature of [`SafeArrayPutElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221283.aspx) requires it to be a pointer, right?)

Comment: Anything that gets the job done is ok with me ;) 

Juddging only from the name, VT_RECORD seemed to be closest option to what I am trying to accomplish. I just need to be able to expose this structure/class to the unmanaged code to populate it.

Comment: Can you elabore on HOW your current solution exactly fails? An error message maybe?

Comment: When I posted this question, I was getting a negative return value from the SafeArrayPutElement. For some reason, this is not happening anymore (not sure what has caused this, maybe jet another clean/rebuild cycle?); now when I run the debugger and step into the managed code, the reference to the class (which I pass via an API) appears to be NULL.

Comment: Actually, the reference to the array of classes is null.

Comment: I have added a bit more context in the code. Note that inside the for loop I am able to succesfully populate and pass to the managed code 2 array of strings. It's just the array of classes which doesn't work for me. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: This looks good to me... Have you tried VT_DISPATCH? or making the class a struct in stead? Otherwise, I don't think I can help any more :(

Comment: I have just tried the VT_DISPATCH seems to do the trick. Thank you a lot!